# Lium SpkDiarization file output

Tags: segmentation-fault

Can any one please explain this in the file output of Lium
cluster S0 [ merge HCLR 0 = S0 in S10 with 1.6663113821146658 ] [ score:FS = -32.61900379113659 ] [ score:FT = -33.825570611325034 ] [ score:MS = -33.39369917293994 ] [ score:MT = -34.19350559383342 ]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. I can't speak for others, but I have no idea what you are asking about. Please visit the [help] and read [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: I'm talking about speaker diarization  with the tool  lium_SpkDiarization, I have an output file that I can't understand cluster S0 [ merge HCLR 0 = S0 in S10 with 1.6663113821146658 ] [ score:FS = -32.61900379113659 ] [ score:FT = -33.825570611325034 ] [ score:MS = -33.39369917293994 ] [ score:MT = -34.19350559383342 ]